# Pool getConnection undefined

Tags: node.js, database-connection, undefined

The problem is when I tried the pool connection via variable I'm getting following error

```
TypeError: sourCon.sourceDBConnection.getConnection is not a function
```

but if I try the normal connection it's fine.

The code is as follows:

**File. ./db/source_db.js**

```
module.exports =
{
    sourceDBConnection: function () {
        return mysql.createPool({
            connectionLimit : 10,
            host     : 'localhost',
            user     : 'root',
            password : '',
            database : 'testdb'
        });
    }
};
```

**File: app.js**

```
app.get('/report-url', function (req, res) {

    corporateModel.DetailReport(dateTime(),request);

})
```

**File. ./models/corporate.js**

```
var sourCon = require("../common_config/source_db");

module.exports =
{

    DetailReport: function (dateTime,request,Q) {

        var whereTripQueryAppend = "";

        sourCon.sourceDBConnection.getConnection(function(err, finConnection) {

            /* Get the last inserted ID */
            finConnection.query("SELECT student_id FROM studen LIMIT 1", function (error, lastResults, fields) {
                /* some process here */
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Do you know why it works for the normal connection and it's not working for the pool connections? Also if I defined the connection in the same file it works fine. AS

**File. ./models/corporate.js**

```
var sourceDBConnection = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'testdb'
});

var sourCon = require("../common_config/source_db");

module.exports =
{

    DetailReport: function (dateTime,request,Q) {

        var whereTripQueryAppend = "";

        sourceDBConnection.getConnection(function(err, finConnection) {

            /* Get the last inserted ID */
            finConnection.query("SELECT student_id FROM studen LIMIT 1", function (error, lastResults, fields) {
                /* some process here */
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Should be `sourCon.sourceDBConnection().getConnection...`, since you've defined it as a function.

Comment: thanks it worked fine.